# next.js getInitialProps in a global layout component

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am buiding a website using next.js and I am trying to wrap my head around the following "problem". I have some static data (website text) that needs to be fetched from an API endpoint (Headless CMS).

For individual pages I use `getInitialProps` to fetch the required data. However I also have a Footer component in my main layout. Both layout and the Footer component have no getInitialProps solution, so how to deal with this in a "nice" way?

Some solutions I thought of:

1. I can use componentDidMount to do a client side fetch for the data in the footer component (But I really want to server fetch / make it static).
2. Move the footer to each page and have `getInitialProps` available, adding some HOC to prevent rewriting all the code.
3. As I said the data is static so make it available globally through server.js or _document.js (I don't know how to accomplish this though).

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your Header and Footer components in your `_app.js`.

First, in `App.getInitialProps`, fetch any data or perform any actions you need to happen server side. Then, this data you return can be returned as props, combined with the result of `Component.getInitialProps` (your page component's getInitialProps).

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
  let pageProps = {};

  // Make any initial calls we need to fetch data required for SSR
  const isAuthed = await ctx.reduxStore.dispatch(checkAuth());

  // Load the page getInitiaProps
  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps({ isAuthed, ...ctx });
  }

  return { pageProps: { ...pageProps, isAuthed } };
  // Or, if the async data is separate from your page props:
  // { pageProps, data: { isAuthed } };
}
```

In your render function you have access to `this.props.pageProps` (or `this.props.data` if you separated it). You can then pass that along to your header and footer.

```
<Header {...pageProps} />
  <main>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </main>
<Footer {...pageProps} />
```